# VK Api messages.get C#

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! Прошу не то чтобы помощи, а больше совета. Делаю standalone приложение, использующее vk api. Так вот хочу, чтобы в моем приложении воспроизводился звук нового сообщения, когда пользователю оно пришло. Была мысль сделать таймер и в нем делать запрос messages.get, но если оставить воспроизведение звука в таймере, то звук будет повторяться, пока пользователь не прочтет все новые сообщения. Так вот как это лучше реализовать, чтобы звук был один раз, когда приходит сообщение?

Comment: а что мешает вам воспроизводить сообщение только один раз, без повторений?

Comment: Так вот я и не понимаю, как мне это сделать...

Comment: ну это довольно просто. Сейчас попробую описать подробнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю логики вашего кода, однако, думаю, можно сделать что-то наподобие:

```
// переменная, в которой нужно хранить статусы сообщений (был ли проигран звук или нет)
Dictionary<int, bool> messages = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

// этот код нужно вызывать при получении сообщения
messages[newMessageId] = false;

// этот код нужно вызывать в таймере
foreach(var message in messages)
{
    if(!message.value) 
    {   
        // ваша функция, вызывающая звуковой сигнал
        Ring(); 
        // устанавливаем флаг, означающий, 
        // что звуковой сигнал по сообщению уже был проигран
        message.Value = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделайте проверку на существование ключа, и если он существует, то менять значение не нужно

Comment: Не можете подсказать, как это примерно сделать?

Comment: юзайте метод ContainsKey у Dictionary

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Тут еще в этом месте ошибка 
// устанавливаем флаг, означающий, 
// что звуковой сигнал по сообщению уже был проигран
message.Value = true;
Говорит: "Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору доступ только для чтения"

Comment: @Adept22 этот код я написал ориентировочно, не имея под рукой компилятора. Разумеется, он может содержать синтаксические ошибки - к сожалению (или к счастью) в голове у меня не компилятора. Цель этого кода - показать вам общий принцип, как именно можно реализовать подобную проверку. Если вам хотя бы немного знаком C#, то предполагается, что решить подобные проблемы с синтаксисом вы должны уметь и сами. Если нет, то вам имеет смысл заняться изучением основ языка

Comment: Да, я понял. Я написал сюда зачем то, а сам исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте push-уведомления. См. [`account.registerDevice()`](https://vk.com/dev/account.registerDevice)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я бы проверил, есть ли новые мессаги, и если есть, то запомнил сколько их и пиликнул. А при нажатии просмотреть запоминал, сколько прочитано. Потом при проверке по таймеру, если есть непрочитанные, то вычитаем от прошлого числа непрочитанных количество нажатий Прочитать. И если больше 0, то пиликаем, )) ну так как-то. А вообще с ВК не работал, но думаю, у каждого сообщения есть ID, и, наверное, он увеличивается с каждым сообщением.

Answer (score -1):

Костыль, конечно) Но может сразу помечать сообщение как прочитанное? А в вашем UI какой-нибудь индикатор наличия новых сообщений.

Как это не содержится? 
Ну вот ссылка на метод для отметки как прочитанное.
https://vk.com/dev/messages.markAsRead
Как я себе это вижу. В цикле в отдельном треде запрашиваешь наличие новых не прочитанных сообщений. 
Если таковые есть, берешь id сообщения и сохраняешь в какой-нибудь лист. Сообщение отмечаешь как прочитанное. Воспроизводишь сигнал. На форме делаешь, например, PicBox с зеленым кружком, который будет сигнализировать о наличии новых сообщений. 
Пользователь кликает по picBox и ему выдаются все непрочитаныне сообщения по idшкам из листа. Лист чистится и работаем далее.